# PHP curl through proxy generating high CPU load

Tags: php, curl, proxy

After investigating the reasons for the high CPU load generated by an application sending many curl requests with 20 parallel PHP-cli scripts, I've found out the main reason is the PROXY option set to the curl handle.

The following code is generating a 0.5-1.5% CPU load at the moment of curl_exec when run without the proxy and 12-25% when using any proxy (I've tried many different ones).

With many threads running many requests at the same time, it soon becomes critical.

I'm using:
Ubuntu 16.04
PHP 7.0.22
curl 7.55.1

Is there a fix or workaround I can apply?

```
$address = 'xxx';
$port = 'xxx';
$url = 'https://api.ipify.org?format=json';

do {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'identity');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $address);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, $port);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    sleep(10);

} while (true);
```